# DB2 select query in NWDS 7.0 not returning any result

Tags: sql, db2

I am having another problem this time and its about DB2 query, running in NWDS.The specification of database which I am using are:

```
Database:-     EP1,
Schema:-       W2HCMSC,
Tablespace:-   W2HCMTS,
Table:-        TESTEMPLOYEE,
Cloumns:-      ZONE, Workshop, Year, Employee Name, Designation, DOB.
```

The snapshot of the database with values is the select statement which I want to run is a select query with where clause but its not returning any row.
These are the details:

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee
```

(4 rows returning)

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where 'w2hcmsc.Zone' = '1'
```

(0 row returning)

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where 'Zone' = 1
```

(SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the
function "DECFLOAT".  SQLSTATE=22018)

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where zone = 1
```

SQL0206N  "ZONE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where Zone = 1
```

SQL0206N  "ZONE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

```sql
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where 'Zone' = '1'
```

(0 record(s) selected).

Please tell me why the select query with where clause is not working. And do I have to write it in any differnt manner?

Answer (score 0):

try the fully qualified name of the column:

```
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where w2hcmsc.testemployee.ZONE = 1
```

or create an alias for the table and use it:

```
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee AS t1 where t1.ZONE = 1
```

Comment: if given t1.Zone and t1.ZONE then i am getting sql error -206. If 't1.Zone' is used the sql error -420 is comming

Comment: I have solved the problem atleast thats what i think. The problem is that in the DB2 the coloumn name were not in all caps but while interpreting the name of the columns are getting transferd from lower case to upper case, so thats why there was a column mismatch. thanks for all the help any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Your column name appears to be in mixed case.  It's generally a good idea to avoid using mixed case in your column names – While DB2 supports this, it creates headaches such as this.

The solution is to quote your column names using double quotes (not single quotes):

```
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee where "Zone" = 1
```

or, using a table correlation name:

```
select * from w2hcmsc.testemployee as t1 where t1."Zone" = 1
```